# Rails: Which oauth/oauth2 middleware to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I am pretty much overwhelmed by the diversity of oauth/oauth2 rack middleware projects on github.

First question: Is oauth deprecated? Am I only up-to-date with an oauth2 middleware? Is oauth1 unsecure?

What if I want to provide an authorization procedure myself? I am sorry if I am not using the oauth terminology correctly. I mean that I don't want - at least not from beginning - to use Provider like Facebook or Twitter for login, but I want to maintain own User Accounts.

Not wanting an external provider (in the beginning at last) I got referenced to OmniAuth Identity.

Letdown: There are almost no tutorials, especially no up-to-date ones. There is mainly only the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity) on it from 2011.

And the examples in the github page only state things like

```
# Anything else you want!
```

or

```
# whatever else you want!
```

Also no Wiki here.

**So what is the to-go-for up-to-date oauth1/2 middleware if you want to be able to take a pass on external providers, please?**

What's with the obviously "vanilla" [OmniAuth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth)

Comment: "First question: Is oauth deprecated?" - that really raises the question of depreciated by whom? While the major providers like Google and Facebook have moved on to OAuth2 - there still exists quite many providers that still use oath 1.

Comment: " to use Provider like Facebook or Twitter for login, but I want to maintain own User Accounts." - In almost any application you'll want to have a table for users. This is how you associate users with all the other resources in the application. OmniAuth is pretty vague by design as its basically just a set of building blocks for authentication. If you want something that is more straight forward setup devise for simple password authentication and then add oauth authentication.

Comment: I will give the `Identity` middleware a try.

Comment: Its not that the question is basic - its that its lacking focus and is so many different questions rolled into one.  That makes it hard to authoritively answer. Ask seperate questions instead. Also recommendations for software, books and such are off-topic.

Comment: I am not a stranger to the one queston per thread policy. I just think that for someone new to the oauth-standard, as the many options and terminology that plays together, it's like a piece of gear wheels, which is why the topic is not bad treated when those questions are asked at once.